# Подключение React на дочерних страницах в Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs

Использую React совместно с WordPress.
На главной странице с формой всё работает как нужно.
Но стоит только перейти с основной страницы на другую - скрипты уже не работают.
Что сделать, чтобы React заработал не только на главной странице?

Подключение на главной странице происходит при помощи файла index.js, содержащий следующую строку кода:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('captcha'));
```

Переходя с главной страницы, а именно - с index.php, работать что-либо перестаёт и я не знаю, каким образом всё подключить.

На главной странице я использую React для заполнения формы, а на одной из дочерних хотел сделать фильтр, под него хотел выделить файл Filter.js

Comment: Приведите в своем вопросе как вы подключаете файлы. Так вам быстрее смогут помочь.

Comment: На главной странице, в файле index.php есть форма, где требуется указать некоторые данные.
К ней я подключаюсь следующим образом:  
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('captcha'));  

Это уже в файле index.js

Comment: Перечитайте еще раз мой комментарий. Комментарии не предназначены для кода.

Comment: Почитайте про роутинг в реакте

Comment: https://javascriptforwp.com/adding-react-to-a-wordpress-theme-tutorial/